# relationship between det and orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, orthogonality

I know that all orthogonal matrices have a $\det$ of either $1$ or $-1$, but I need to know if this statement goes both ways.

**My question:**  If $\det$ of a matrix $= -1$ or $1$ does that matrix HAVE TO BE orthogonal? and if not, why?(and if $\det = -1$ or $1$ and not orthogonal is possible then  can I get an example of one such matrix)

Comment: Any triangular matrix with ones along the diagonal has unit determinant.

Answer (score 4):

As intuition behind determinant is about volume of the shape with sides of the vectors, so, we can have a shape with volume equal to one, although its sides are not orthogonal.

Comment: Ok, I think i understand it now. The analogy helped. Also side question if you don't mind me asking does the transpose of a orthogonal matrix = the inverse?

Comment: @LKRC: Yes, that's the definition of what it means to be an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Try the matrix 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
with determinant $1$. Are the columns orthogonal?

Comment: .............,,no?

Comment: @LKRC no they are not, their dot product is 1.

Answer (score 1):

In an orthogonal matrix every column (and row) should be a unit vector.
So no entry in a column (or row) can exceed  $+1$
Using  this remark we can easily generate lot of matrices of determinant 1 that are not orthogonal

Take two consecutive integers that are not prime and factorize them both: for example $44,45$ factorized as $44= 11\times 4,\ 45= 5\times 9$. So $1=45-44 = 5\times9-11\times4$.

The  matrix $A=\pmatrix{5& 11\cr 4 & 9\cr}$ has determinat 1 and entries are bigger than 1 so its columns are not unit vectors.

In general take an $n\times n$ matrix $B$ whose determinant $\Delta$ is a positive number.
Now divide each entry of the first row by $\Delta$. This new matrix will have determinant 1 and most of the times non-orthogonal (arrange to have 2 as an entry in the 2nd row, for example)

Comment: And if the columns are all unit vectors and the determinant is one?

Answer (score 0):

I wish it did go both ways but the determinant mixes vector magnitude information with vector direction information.

Orthogonality is a relationship between vector directions but completely ignores the magnitudes of the vectors. If you can assume vector magnitudes are all one (i.e. all unit vectors), you can use the determinant to measure degree of orthogonality between vectors.